# Why use Grafbase with Graphql?

Tags: next.js, graphql

I ran into Grafbase being used with Graphql and now I am not sure what is the role of Grafbase in Graphql. I far as I know graphql is a query language that is used to create queries for fetching data avoiding overfetching and underfetching unlike REST API. but what role does Grafbase play here? is it a database like Mongodb which servers data using graphql api's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie from Grafbase here

Grafbase aims to reduce the complexity around creating GraphQL APIs and unifying data sources. Grafbase automatically generates GraphQL APIs from an existing GraphQL or OpenAPI spec too.

You can think of Grafbase as a fully managed GraphQL Yoga or Apollo Server but with all of the bells and whistles, including [caching](https://grafbase.com/edge-caching), [auth/permissions](https://grafbase.com/auth), [branch previews](https://grafbase.com/branching) and more.

Grafbase currently has its own lightweight database, but you can integrate any database using resolvers. See a few of these examples to get you going:

- https://github.com/grafbase/grafbase/tree/main/examples/resolvers-mongodb
- https://github.com/grafbase/grafbase/tree/main/examples/resolvers-turso

To make the experience even more significant for developers wanting to use their existing database, we will soon introduce native database connectors.

The first is MongoDB; you can get a sneak peek of what this looks like currently [here](https://github.com/grafbase/grafbase/pull/544).

We recently updated the [homepage](https://grafbase.com/) that includes a config builder which should give you a better idea of how to connect existing data sources, configure auth, serverless search index, caching and more.

The thing we see a lot of developers using Grafbase for currently is to cache and extend existing GraphQL or OpenAPIs — [learn more](https://grafbase.com/guides/extend-any-graphql-api-with-data-from-other-apis).